# Is there any way to bind datatable row to DataGrid in UWP

Tags: c#, excel, uwp

I want to show **rows of datatable** in [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid). I take data from excel and want to show them in the UWP table, but the excel table has many columns and it is bad to create an object with this many parameters. Can I bind data from datatable to DataGrid just using columns names from the Datatable?

Comment: Hello, DataGrid can automatically generate columns based on the type of bound object, which uses reflection internally. The recommended approach is to bind an object corresponding to a data table (that is, including all properties). If the DataTable you are referring to is a database object, it may not be directly bound to the DataGrid (need to be converted into an instance object first)

Comment: I think you need to define an object model first.